# Beep code for Dell Poweredge T105

Tags: dell-poweredge

I can't start my Poweredge T-105 just after two years. It does not display any on monitor but blue lights on 3 & 4 of system case. And it repeatedly beeps.

At first, it beeps 1-3-3 and then repeats 1-1-3-4.

As far as I can search on the net, Dell's beep code is 3 digit. So do I have to consider the beep code for my error is 1-3-3?

Unfortunately, my warranty expired last year so any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waged on 1-3-3 beep code: `Chip or data line failure in the first 64 KB of main memory` according to Dell's documentation.

So I experimented with each of four memory chips in the computer and found bad one after four trials. Hope it helps someone with similar difficulty.